# Removing wood stain from a ceramic surface

Tags: everyday-chemistry, ceramics

I have a bathtub that I accidentally poured wood stain into. Now the stain is all over the white ceramic surface of the tub. I tried using bleach but it didn't do anything. I'm curious if there is a chemist who would know the answer.

I used [Varathane® Premium Fast Dry Interior Oil-Base Cabernet Wood Stain](https://www.menards.com/main/paint/interior-paint-stain/interior-stain/oil-based-stain/varathane-reg-premium-fast-dry-interior-oil-base-wood-stain-1-2-pt/262035/p-1444452960121-c-7972.htm?tid=-8131903479009969683&ipos=11) with the following properties ([Technical Specifications — PDF](https://hw.menardc.com/main/items/media/RUSTO001/Prod_Tech_Spec/VarathaneFastDryWoodStain.pdf)):

> [image: properties chart]

Comment: Try some acetone (nail varnish remover) or white spirit on a small area.

Comment: **CAREFUL** - You may have plastic drain pipes and it would be  very bad to have acetone in contact with such pipes. Also acetone is very flammable so you need very good ventilation.